# Modify Bootstrap's navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have applied a style of padding left to the #my_account li. But I don't want that style applied when the navbar is collapsed.

Does anyone know on how I can have that style only when the navbar is not collapsed? Thanks!

**CSS**

```
#my_account {
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top' role='navigation' ">
    <div class="fluid" >
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav_bar_collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav_bar_collapsed">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Freelancers
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                        <a href="#">Manage Hired Freelancers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Manage Applicants</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Project To Do List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                    <!-- Email Templates , Account Setting, Finical Summary, Contact Us Log Out-->
                    <li id="my_account"><a href="#">My Account</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found out the answer after doing more research. This is what I did

Show apply the padding when the navbar is not collapsed

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #my_account {
        padding-left: 60px;
    }
}
```